# web applications not showing up during configuration of shared service provider

Tags: sharepoint

When i tried to create Shared Service on sharepoint server 2007 web application's not showing up during configuration of shared service. I used my user name on predefined instead of network services. In that time web application listed but it comes error page "Provisioning failed: Windows NT user or group 'DOMAIN\adadmin' not found. Check the name again".

Answer (score 0):

Is the SharePoint server on the same domain as the account your using? Does the account exist? Is the account active? (i.e. not disabled or locked)

Comment: Yes SharePoint server on the same domain as the account , yes exist and yes active.